# Flutter Firebase merge: true not working as intended?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a Map item to my existing list of items on my firebase database. However, whenever I use the method    setData(data, merge:true) it ***replaces my existing one with the new data***. I am trying to figure out how I should go about it and add a new item whenever the user pressed a button.

Thanks for your help in advance

Here's my code for uploading the item:

```
Future<void> uploadItem(
    String location,
    String sellerName,
    String uid,
    String itemName,
    String itemDescription,
    String itemPrice,
    String units,
    String deliveryLocation,
    String itemType,
    String deliveryDate,
    String sellbyDate,
    File image) async {
        var currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
        String imagePath; // To be added later
        var data = {
             'Seller Name': sellerName,
             'Item Name': itemName,
             'Item Description': itemDescription,
             'Item Type': itemType,
             'Item Price': itemPrice,
             'Units': units,
             'Delivery Location': deliveryLocation,
             'Delivery Date': deliveryDate,
             'Sell-by Date': sellbyDate,
             'Image Path': imagePath,
        };
  await dbReference.collection(location).document(currentUser.uid).setData(data, merge: true);
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to describe in more detail exactly what is being overwritten that is different than what you expect. It would be helpful if you show examples of the document both before and after the update to make it clear what you are confused about.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a same issue. You can fix it in new version of Flutter as below:

```
Future<void> uploadItem(
    String location,
    String sellerName,
    String uid,
    String itemName,
    String itemDescription,
    String itemPrice,
    String units,
    String deliveryLocation,
    String itemType,
    String deliveryDate,
    String sellbyDate,
    File image) async {
        var currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
        String imagePath; // To be added later
        var data = {
             'Seller Name': FieldValue.arrayUnion([sellerName]),
             'Item Name': FieldValue.arrayUnion([itemName]),
             'Item Description': FieldValue.arrayUnion([itemDescription]),
             'Item Type': FieldValue.arrayUnion([itemType]),
             'Item Price': FieldValue.arrayUnion([itemPrice]),
             'Units': FieldValue.arrayUnion([units]),
             'Delivery Location': FieldValue.arrayUnion([deliveryLocation]),
             'Delivery Date': FieldValue.arrayUnion([deliveryDate]),
             'Sell-by Date': FieldValue.arrayUnion([sellbyDate]),
             'Image Path': FieldValue.arrayUnion([imagePath]),
        };
  await dbReference.collection(location).document(currentUser.uid).set(data, SetOptions(merge : true));
}
```